# Connector routing configuration error ` unexpected token "<EOF>" (expected ")" Key*)`

Tags: open-telemetry

I'm trying to configurate connector routing, but get compilation error.

```
---
extensions:
  zpages: null
receivers:
  filelog:
    exclude: []
    include:
      - /TODA/bench_log/*.log
    include_file_name: true
    include_file_path: true
    operators:
      - field: attributes.log
        type: add
        value: unspecified
      - field: attributes.ct
        type: add
        value: unspecified
      - field: attributes.scid
        type: add
        value: unspecified
      - field: attributes.sysid
        type: add
        value: unspecified
      - field: attributes.sev
        type: add
        value: unspecified
      - field: attributes.ts
        type: add
        value: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000 UTC
      - field: attributes.mid
        type: add
        value: unspecified
      - type: json_parser
      - mapping:
          fatal: emergency
          info4: notice
        parse_from: attributes.sev
        type: severity_parser
      - from: attributes.log
        id: move1
        to: resource["Log Message"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.ct
        id: move2
        to: resource["Container Name"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.scid
        id: move3
        to: resource["Unique Container ID"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.sysid
        id: move4
        to: resource["System ID"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.sev
        id: move5
        to: resource["Severity"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.ts
        id: move6
        to: resource["Timestamp"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.mid
        id: move7
        to: resource["Message ID"]
        type: move
      - from: attributes.log.file.name
        id: copy1
        to: resource["FileName"]
        type: copy        

    resource:
      - dataType: bigipn-pods-log
    start_at: beginning
    
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4617
        tls:
          cert_file: ${OTEL_TLS_CERT_FILE}
          client_ca_file: ${OTEL_TLS_CA_FILE}
          key_file: ${OTEL_TLS_KEY_FILE}
          min_version: "1.2"
          reload_interval: 100000
  
processors:
  batch: null
exporters:
    file:
      path: /var/log/otlp.json
    logging:
      sampling_initial: 0
      sampling_thereafter: 0
      verbosity: basic
    otlp/2c27f38b-3399-4531-b66c-f557f646ebb0:
        endpoint: 1.1.1.1:4417
        sending_queue:
            enabled: true
            queue_size: 5
        retry_on_failure:
            enabled: true
            initial_interval: 2s
            max_elapsed_time: 6s
        tls:
            insecure: true
    otlp/ccb8b939-5dab-465f-bcf4-921385d8001d:
        endpoint: 1.1.1.1:4517
        sending_queue:
            enabled: true
            queue_size: 5
        retry_on_failure:
            enabled: true
            initial_interval: 2s
            max_elapsed_time: 6s
        tls:
            insecure: true
    otlp/fd71bd0c-de38-4512-8a78-f07918f9a0ea:
        endpoint: 1.1.1.1:4317
        sending_queue:
            enabled: true
            queue_size: 5
        retry_on_failure:
            enabled: true
            initial_interval: 2s
            max_elapsed_time: 6s
        tls:
            insecure: true
connectors:
  routing/logs:
      default_pipelines: [logs/otlp-all]
      error_mode: propagate
      table:
        - statement: route() where IsMatch(attributes["FileName"],".*access*.log"
          pipelines: [logs/container, logs/access]
        - statement: route() where (IsMatch((attributes["FileName"],".*.log")) and not IsMatch(attributes["FileName"],".*access*.log") and not IsMatch(attributes["FileName"],".*waf*.log"))
          pipelines: [logs/container]
        - statement: route() where IsMatch(attributes["FileName"],".*waf*.log"
          pipelines: [logs/waf]
  routing/metrics:
      default_pipelines: [metrics/1]
      error_mode: propagate
      table:
        - statement: route() where attributes["dataType"] == "type1"
          pipelines: [metrics/1]
        - statement: route() where attributes["dataType"] == "type2"
          pipelines: [metrics/2]
        - statement: route() where attributes["dataType"] == "type3"
          pipelines: [metrics/3]
service:
  pipelines:
    logs/in:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [routing/logs]
    logs/otlp-all:
      exporters:
        - logging
      receivers:
        - routing/logs  
    logs/access:
      exporters:
        - logging
        - otlp/ccb8b939-5dab-465f-bcf4-921385d8001d
      receivers:
        - routing/logs
    logs/container:
      exporters:
        - logging
        - otlp/2c27f38b-3399-4531-b66c-f557f646ebb0
      receivers:
        - routing/logs
    logs/waf:
      exporters:
        - logging
        - otlp/fd71bd0c-de38-4512-8a78-f07918f9a0ea
      receivers:
        - routing/logs
    metrics/in:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [routing/metrics]
    metrics/1:
      exporters:
        - logging
        - otlp/2c27f38b-3399-4531-b66c-f557f646ebb0
      receivers:
        - routing/metrics
    metrics/2:
      exporters:
        - logging
        - otlp/ccb8b939-5dab-465f-bcf4-921385d8001d
      receivers:
        - routing/metrics
    metrics/3:
      exporters:
        - logging
        - otlp/fd71bd0c-de38-4512-8a78-f07918f9a0ea
      receivers:
        - routing/metrics
  extensions:
    - zpages
```

The error I get:

```
otel-contrib  | Error: failed to build pipelines: statement has invalid syntax: 1:61: unexpected token "<EOF>" (expected ")" Key*)
otel-contrib  | 2023/10/24 16:01:30 collector server run finished with error: failed to build pipelines: statement has invalid syntax: 1:61: unexpected token "<EOF>" (expected ")" Key*)
```

What is the problem?

I'm trying to run otel contrib, expect for no error and loading application

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with ')'

- statement: route() where IsMatch(attributes["FileName"],".*access*.log")
  pipelines: [logs/container, logs/access]
  - statement: route() where (IsMatch(attributes["FileName"], ".*.log") and not IsMatch(attributes["FileName"], ".*access*.log") and not IsMatch(attributes["FileName"], ".*waf*.log"))
  pipelines: [logs/container]
  - statement: route() where IsMatch(attributes["FileName"],".*waf*.log")
  pipelines: [logs/waf]